# How to purge references to me when referring to project I made

Tags: word-choice

> There is a project I have been working on in my free time, named the
> ********. The primary objective of...

In the above sentence, I would like to remove the 'I', but I'm not sure how. The structure of the sentence may be changed, but the fundamental meaning should stay true: That I'm working on a project.

**NOTE:** Things like 'my' will not exactly solve my problem. As I'm looking to remove all references to me. However, any answer you have is welcomed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for writing advice rather than advice on grammar, word meanings, or punctuation. I'll add one suggestion: '... a project occupying only free time, and on which no one else has been working'. But using 'I' is far more sensible and less clumsy; only people who need to adjust their evaluation systems would consider it egotistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**extracurricular** as an adjective and careful phrasing.

*Project X is an **extracurricular** project, developed completely [outside of work-hours OR during spare-time.]*

It formally refers to school and being outside the course of study, but has evolved to include outside of normal duties. [See definition 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extracurricular)

> Definition of extracurricular
> 1 : not falling within the scope of a regular curriculum 
> 2a : lying outside one's regular duties or routine
> b : EXTRAMARITAL

Comment: This is the best answer. However, I don't need an answer anymore as I just settled with using 'I'. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only way not to refer to yourself is not to do so, but you could *imply* it.

> The all-consuming spare time project is called ...

Comment: I don't need an answer anymore as I just settled with using 'I'. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You obfuscate completely the origin of your work as being yourself in the solution proposed below; however you make your reader quite expectant as to who is the author and you will have sooner or later --it'll be better sooner than later-- to fill that gap in the explanation they get from you; but perhaps you are trying to manage a certain effect and the revelation would be best if postponed longer, that is according to the idea you have of this effect.

- There is a project whose author worked on in his/her free time, named the ********. The primary objective of...

Comment: I don't need an answer anymore as I just settled with using 'I'. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to rephrase the essential part of the sentence:

- **A** project being worked on is the ********. The primary objective of...
- **One** project being worked on is the ********. The primary objective of...

---

It's not possible to directly rephrase *in my free time* into an objective statement that doesn't sound stilted and unnatural.

However, if you do something in your free time, that often means that it takes a while to complete. That sense of duration could be added to the sentence while still keeping it sounding normal:

- (A / One) project being **slowly** worked on is the ********. The primary objective of...
- (A / One) project **in continual development** is the ********. The primary objective of...

---

Since this question has been locked, and I am unable to post a comment, I can't ask for clarification about the context. Knowing the context could change the specific nature of any rephrased sentence.

Comment: I am showing a project to someone, and would like to refrain from using any references to myself. However, I don't need an answer anymore as I just settled with using 'I'. Thanks anyway.